# How to update an item inside a map in firestore with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I have a question on updating items in firestore. Lets assume we have follwing structure

```
"content" -> document -> 
"questions": 
[
{
"q" : "Are you good?", 
"info" : "Just say yes or no"
}, 
{
"q" : "are you playing ball", 
"info" : "football, soccer, basketbal.."
}
]
```

Now a user is answering a question, I want to save the answer inside the array in the map of the specific question like:

```
"content" -> document -> 
"questions": 
[
{
"q" : "Are you good?", 
"info" : "Just say yes or no",
"answer" : "yes"
}, 
{
"q" : "are you playing ball", 
"info" : "football, soccer, basketball..",
"answer" : "no"
}
]
```

at the first time that is no problem, the question get saved like that, with the snapshot of the original question, the current index and the given answer:

```
void _onPressed(AsyncSnapshot snapshot, index, answer) async {
var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
Map<String, dynamic> someData = {
    "q": snapshot.data!["questions"][index]["q"],
    "info": snapshot.data!["questions"][index]["info"],
    "answer": answer
  };
await firestoreInstance
      .collection("test")
      .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
      .collection("content")
      .doc("document")
      .update({
    "questions": FieldValue.arrayUnion([someData]),
  }).then((_) {
    print("success!");
  });
}
```

But if the user goes back to the question and changes his answer it will just create a new entry instead of changing "yes" to "no" for the specific question:

```
"content" -> document -> 
"questions": 
[
{
"q" : "Are you good?", 
"info" : "Just say yes or no",
"answer" : "yes"
}, 
{
"q" : "are you playing ball", 
"info" : "football, soccer, basketball..",
"answer" : "no"
},
{
"q" : "are you playing ball", 
"info" : "football, soccer, basketball..",
"answer" : "yes"
}
]
```

Is there any way of just changing the 1 item (answer) in the map inside the array?? Maybe the data model doesnt make sense? I really have no idea, I tried a lot of different approaches...

thx for helping

Comment: How many questions can a document have? It'll be easier to do what you want if the questions were in a map or a sub-collection.

Comment: There can be 10 or more question per doc. It is basically the category of questions and all questions related to it. you meam a subcollection per question?

Comment: No, a sub-collection having containing all questions in their own document.

Comment: What would it change? then I have a collection "questions" -> 0 -> {"q" : "question2", "info" : "info1"} and "questions" -> 1 -> {"q" : "question2", "info" : "info2"} right? Then it is also harder to go from one question to the next and have related questions like "Do you play Basketball?" if "yes" -> "Do you have your own Basketball at home?" which would not make sense if he answers "no"

Comment: I'd recommend using random Firestore doc IDs for each question. So when user answers a question, check the question ID on frontend and update the relevant document.

Comment: Could you give an example? I am not sure how you can handle stuff like "next question" or "jump to question".. with that! Because than you have to work with multiple collections and don't have "set" or update and need to get each doc seperatly...